# Is there a way to know if Tkinter optionmenu dropdown is active ?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm writing a Tkinter program where I have an option menu with other UI elements. I have a requirement that if optionmenu drop down remains active for a particular time (say 1 minute), I need to close drop down menu and cancel the selection. I was wondering if there is a way to know if an optionmenu dropdown is active. I've looked at [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/iwidgets3.0/optionmenu.n.html) particular link but couldn't locate any specific method for what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping track of whether the menu is closed or open is easily done with a command and click binding.  The hard part is forcing the menu to close.  Either a physical mouse click off the widget or press of Escape will do so.  But generating events does not do.  The #commented_out bits below are failed experiments.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
n = 2
after_id = None
menu_open = False
omvar = tk.StringVar(root)

def timeout():
    print('timeout called')
    omvar.set('')
    #root.event_generate('<Key-Escape>', keysym='Escape', keycode=9)
    #om.destroy()
    #root.event_generate('<FocusIn>')
    #root.focus_get()
    #root.event_generate('<Button-1>', x=10, y=20)
    root.update()


def open(event):
    print('open called')
    global after_id, menu_open
    after_id = root.after(n*1000, timeout)
    menu_open = True

def close(val):
    print('closed by', val)
    global after_id, menu_open
    root.after_cancel(after_id)
    after_id = None
    menu_open = False

om = tk.OptionMenu(root, omvar, 'a', 'b', 'c', command=close)
om.bind('<Button-1>', open)
om.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

A MenuButton + Menu would look nearly the same and might be easier.  Would you consider that?

Comment: I ended up using Pymouse library to simulate a button click and now it works perfectly along with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

First define a variable,(for example: ddo = 0)
Then Trigger a click on your dropdownlist, when clicked, toggle ddo = 1(if ddo == 1 then ddo = 0)
and when ddo == 1 a timer start to count for 1second, after that 1second if ddo == 1, then close selectbox(for example by focusing on another element) and do what ever you want. an example pseudo code is here:

```
def OnClick(event):
    if(ddo == 0):
        ddo = 1
        startTimerForOneSec(whenFinished=finishTimer())
    else:
        ddo = 0

    def finishTimer():
        if(ddo == 1):
            focusOneSomeOtherElements()
            doSomeThingElse()
```